# Is there a reason almost every "Hot Question" on Stack Overflow is about C++?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

Since I've started using the Hot Questions, I've noticed a good 80% of all questions on Stack Overflow that appear there are to do with C++. Is there something about C++ questions that naturally give them the "Hot" factor? Or is this just a coincidence?

Some extra information: The only C++ questions I've ever looked at have been from the Hot Questions list, I've never asked/answered one, and I don't have C++ as a favourite tag.

Comment: Obligatory meta joke about C++ programmers having abnormally high average temperatures.

Comment: Hmm, I feel that may be a joke I don't know. Time to Google :P.

Comment: I do and there are loads of C++ vultures who manage to pounce on a question within a minute giving a detailed answer and get +50 rep for it. Or even a "no" answer and get +41 rep or so for it

Comment: Hmm... looking at the Hot Questions, I see far fewer C++ ones than C# ones. Perhaps it's personalized? (When logged out, there aren't many C++ questions either...)

Comment: The [c++] tag has a very stable community, guys that have been around for years and rarely visit other tags.  They do get their share of dreary homework questions, but when a good post appears then they are not afraid to use their votes.  Easily gets to 10+ score in a hurry.  It just snowballs from there, such a post is almost automatically "hot".

Comment: @JonSkeet That's because *you're* the one making all the C# questions hot. When you're asleep, C++ reigns supreme. :P:P:P

Comment: @TomHart: Tim is insinuating C++ questions come pre-heated.

Comment: @Mysticial Jon Skeet, is _never_ asleep.

Comment: C++ people are very exact thinkers (by necessity). The easier a language the more casual programmers who don't value good code. C++ has a high-quality audience.

Comment: @usr The harder the language, the easier it is to write crap with it.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: Not necessarily. You can write as much crap in C++ as you can in PHP, but most of it won't even come close to compiling. In PHP it just sort of spits out warnings at runtime ;p

Comment: C++ attracts the smartypants.

Comment: Now I also wonder: Is there a reason that almost all most upvoted questions with no-answers usually are about Haskell?

Comment: @FurkanOmay: Because Haskell is esoteric as @!#$?

Comment: @Josh That's slightly misleading as many C++ questions are now tagged like "c++ c++11"; you would need to adjust your jQuery to count _questions_ with matching tags, not the tags themselves.

Comment: It's because you c++! Get it? hahaha.

Programmers usually start off at c and c++ so that's why they are always in the heat!

Comment: @FurkanOmay I woould suggest that it is because StackOverflow is not high-brow enough to those able to answer a Haskell question. They don't mingle with the crowds.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

C++ has the magical trifecta for hotness:

1. Being ridiculously complicated and prone to interesting questions about its foibles that attract experts ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25693676/560648));
2. Being incredibly popular, powering a huge range of technologies throughout global infrastructure, with expert developers whose experience spans two or three *decades*;
3. Being ever-changing, with a new standard approved only a week ago, just three years after the previous one.

Other expert languages like Haskell are not as popular, and other popular languages like PHP or C# are not really "expert"; they tend to attract predominantly *fix-my-codez* rubbish. C++ does too, but somehow the C++ community seems better at closing and deleting this nonsense.

Comment: Fewer idiots try to, or succeed at coding in anything that'll run in C++. PHP's running-out-of-the-box ease to get started also makes it easier for the idiots to find the shotgun without any prior experience with aiming. Ergo, more idiots come up with PHP questions than they do C++ questions.

Comment: +1 for "they tend to attract predominantly fix-my-codez rubbish". Even if I get  some rep out of this...

Comment: _"...C++ community seems better at closing and deleting this nonsense"_ If this is followed in other "popular" language communities too, SO incoming posts will be drastically reduced, IMO.

Comment: @P0W: Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: All a question needs to become hot is a good head count of those interested in it. It doesn't say anything about their expert level. So, apart from being boastful about the greatness of C++, I don't see how this answer provides insight into the specific difference that makes C++ stand out in the number of upvoted questions.

Comment: @Marko: Dumb questions do not attract tens of upvotes. It's a fact.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's just reiterating my point: a question *perceived* as dumb doesn't get upvoted. Based on that observation alone the prediction would be that in any compact community, populated with persons of similar expertise and intelligence---no matter how high or low---there should be a lot of upvoting.

Comment: @Marko Ah well the other factor is that non-experts don't tend to spend much time reviewing posts that are not their own. In general. (Though, the review queues confound that a little.)

Comment: I take it for granted that the StackOverflow is comprised of answerers, not askers. And obviously, reviewing others' posts is *the thing* you do on SO as an answerer. For fresh questions, those votes are 99% by answerers.

Comment: Most coding newbies don't know what C++ is there for. Most development is mobile app or website and so they might use PHP or Javascript for the web app or objective-C or android API for phone app and server side might use Java or Python.

Comment: Nothing wrong with all your statements but don't forget that there are also PHP experts and PHP can also be used in a professional manner.

Comment: Is no.3 supposed to be facetious? 3 years since the last spec change, and 8 years before that, really isn't "ever-changing". Each spec changes the language as much as new increments of other languages.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: do not scare me off. There are plenty of silly questions in the C++ tag, too. If there is even more in python, php, etc, I will go hide and cry.

Comment: @lpapp Best stock up on tissues.

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine There is something to the *magnitude* of changes with each iteration of the standard. C++ makes quite large leaps.

Comment: @Evil The changes are paradigm-shifting, and the incremental nature of compiler support means that the user of some particular toolchain will see big changes once or more per year.

Comment: Existence of UB and no native libraries similar to .Net for C# is drawback for C++

Comment: @Giorgi: I disagree. I enjoy not being burdened by force with what some developer in the USA thinks is a great idea.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit didn't get it. but ok people have different opinions. UB is tricky anyway..

Answer (score 27):

C++ is a hot subject, it is a native development language, and people look for how to create the best software tools available to use for the application level technologies.

C++ has had a new standard change in 2011, the first since 2003 and the first major change since the introduction of STL in the late 1990s.

So obviously there are a lot of questions about the new features of C++.

C++ is going through a further change in 2014, so obviously again it is a hot topic.

C++ tends to attract mostly advanced programmers, often systems programmers, often those who are going to be writing the underlying systems to the new tech, for example, most of Google's underlying systems are written in C++.

Those are several reasons why C++ might be a "hot" subject.

Comment: Ahh, I have notice a lot of the questions mentioning C++11 and C++14, I guess that will be the updates.

Comment: I think it's also good to mention that many universities teach C++, particularly in certain countries it seems to be taught first.

Comment: Although the language is called "C++11", it's likely many companies will only just be switching over to it now. It isn't really a switch as such as allowing new features as you change compiler.

Comment: I think the university issue would produce more newbie questions, not the likely hot ones.

Comment: @eddie_cat: Yeah, what CashCow said. Low-scored/closed questions don't really count as "hot". :)

Comment: I don't see how this post even attempts to answer the question. You seem to be trying to answer why there are many c++ questions, not why they get upvotes. Are "advanced aystem programmers" notorious for their upvoting proficiency?

Comment: I am suggesting why people who are relative expert at C++ would still ask questions, and thus why such questions might be considered "hot" especially as several people of C++ expertise might want to know the same and thus upvote them.

Comment: Another reason: there's a lot of questions double-tagged as both C and C++, so C++ gets some extra attention there. For example, I personally only follow the C tag, but still the statistics say that roughly one fifth of the C posts I make also create a C++ post.

Answer (score 8):

Let's see why a person would be compelled to upvote a question:

1. the upvoter shares interest in the topic of the question;
2. the upvoter approves of question's quality, regardless of interest in the topic.

For 1., a community of highly enthusiastic people, especially those who have a lot to learn, would be expected to produce many hot questions.

For 2., a community of exacting people, those who take the quality of posts very personally and emotionally, would be expected to produce many hot questions, as well as many downvote-hammered ones.

Now, it seems that C++ has a community where questions benefit from the effects of both 1. and 2.:

- it is a *fast-paced* language, getting many improvements and frequent updates of the standard, therefore generating a lot of questions about the new features;
- it is an *exacting* language, especially attractive to devoted, highly motivated enthusiasts, who have strong opinions on what is crap and what is praiseworthy;
- it is a *widely used* language, having a quite strong community on a purely numerical scale.

As an additional confirmation, the C++ tag also seems to boast an unusually high level of passionate downvoting, closing, and deleting.

Comment: Well, I downvote, but I rarely do it with much passion.

Comment: +1 for the approach "Let's see why a person would be compelled..."