# Preventing questions falling into a specific language's "Shark Tank"

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm often coming over questions that might be legit, but have improper tags. Here are some recent samples

- [C Looping a switch using Y/N options. Choosing N doesn't close the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710062/c-looping-a-switch-using-y-n-options-choosing-n-doesnt-close-the-program)
- [How to extract the information(such as edge and vertex) from Solidworks files(SLDASM, SLDPRT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691667/how-to-extract-the-informationsuch-as-edge-and-vertex-from-solidworks-filessl#comment40155570_25691667)

I've edited the tags, to remove improper language specific tags that aren't directly related to what shows up in the question.

Though these edits may prevent being the question downvoted by *Falling into a language specific [**shark tank**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261280/1413395)*, the further popularity and interest of this question may seriously decrease.

What's the better reaction in your opinion?

- Remove tags to focus on the specialized aspect of the question
- Let the OP run against the wall of making a precise language specific question (and vote to close the question as not giving all of the specific and relevant information)

Comment: How about stop vandalizing OP's post that clearly says they're using C++?

Comment: @Wooble The OP's don't know what they're doing actually, neither they certainly stated so :P ...

Comment: The first edit history is pretty ridiculous. Let the OP decide what he wants to ask about. For the second, I see no reason to remove all language tags especially if they mention it in the body. If it is off-topic, just close it.

Comment: The second question is clearly too broad; you're doing the site a disservice by trying to get it less attention by removing an oft-followed tag.

Comment: @Anonymous _"For the second ..."_ Let that question go along with the  [tag:c++] tag, and it's doomed quickly.

Comment: If by doomed you mean closed, then perfect.

Comment: @Anonymous Yes of course I meant that, but without the language specific tags, the questions are still legit. That's all about my point.

Comment: Not really... I can think of a few close reasons: *too broad*, *asking for recommendations*, *opinion based*, probably a *duplicate*.

Comment: @Anonymous At least not appropriate for these specific samples i gave here. And these kind are in question.

Comment: @Wooble I'm pretty sure accusing this behavior as being _vandalizing_ a question isn't appropriate!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you jumped out of the frying pan and into the fire. Meta is worse than [c++]. :/

Comment: @user000001 Sure I know! I'm appreciating the challenge ;P ... Cya!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "C++ shark tank" is a red herring here. **The fundamental problem in both cases lies with the question itself.**

In the first example, the asker hasn't made is sufficiently clear what language he is using. The body text clearly states that it is C++, but the code is apparently written in C. The inclusion of `stdio.h`, and especially the use of `printf` and `scanf`, are telling. Someone needs to ask this user which language he *is* using or *intends* to be using. Until that is answered, the question cannot be reasonably answered—and should therefore be closed to prevent an influx of answers that will become *wrong* as soon as the necessary clarification is made.

Note, of course, that heavy-handed editing is not appropriate in this case. You can't just pick either the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) or [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag to remove. The choice would depend strictly on your whimsy, since there are mixed signals coming from the question.

I don't think people asking this question in the comments about which language the asker is actually using counts as falling into a "shark tank". Those are some pretty tame sharks.

In the second example, the question is straight up off-topic. The choice of tags is irrelevant—he could have thrown the [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tags in there, too. It wouldn't have made any difference. There are at least three inherent problems with the question content:

1. It is unfocused and asks too many different questions.
2. It is too broad, mainly because it doesn't give enough detailed information about the asker's unique requirements.
3. It is a recommendation question, twice over.

And that's not even considering the cosmetic problems, like a poor title and a noisy signature.

This question, too, should be closed, at least until it can be banged into shape by a substantial edit. Closure of a question that is unclear, too broad, or off-topic is not "sharky" behavior, it is standard practice on this site, called out very clearly in the Tour for new users. It would (and should) happen regardless of which tags were applied to the question.

It [has been suggested recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270734/is-there-a-reason-almost-every-hot-question-on-stack-overflow-is-about-c) that the users who regularly monitor the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag are quick to vote on, close, and delete questions, according to their perception of quality. This is something I see as a good thing. It would be nice if we could encourage this type of behavior for *other* tags, not discourage it for the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag.

And we certainly don't want to suggest that users shy away from tagging their C++ questions appropriately because they might fall into a "shark tank". If there are sharks in these waters, they're a special species—the kind that you really want to answer your programming question.

[image]

Comment: THX a lot, that makes sense. I'll leave my question here (despite of any downvotes), because it really clarifies about my doubts what's the best way to react.