# Why has this question been closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close, close-reasons, closed-questions

This is the question (from some other author): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896261/please-find-the-error-in-my-code

The reason says:

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close
> gave this specific reason:
>
> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")
> must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
> shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
> Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
> readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
> example.

Maybe I skipped something... but I could find what the above paragraph requires: desired behaviour, the specific error, the shortest code.

Still, it was closed almost immediately. Why? Due to the stupid title? Wouldn't have an edit solved that easier?

Comment: I would also suspect that it's due to the hilariously bad title. Don't forget that it's much easier to downvote+close than to fix. Especially when there's so many other (better) questions to look at.

Comment: The C++ community here is a prickly bunch.  Don't ask them a question unless you've thoroughly debugged your issue.  Also, code dumps won't help you--relevant sections only.

Comment: @Will http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270863/preventing-questions-falling-into-a-specific-languages-shark-tank

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The title was hilariously bad. More importantly, when reading it as a reviewer; **I didn't see the question**.

The OP said that they got 2 and 2 as factors, when they expected 2, 2, and 2. That's exactly what they should include in the question, but it was buried in the "what I am trying to do" section. So buried, in fact, that I nearly answered this by saying that the OP didn't have a problem statement (note: "It doesn't work" is *not* a problem statement).

With such a bad title; people are going to already be predisposed towards closing it, so if a quick read results in them saying "I don't see the question" then they will VTC and move on. With so many questions in C++, there simply isn't enough time to carefully read everything.

In the future; the OP needs to make sure that the problem statement is clear, and come up with a more... useful, title. Other than that, the question should be re-opened in my opinion.

Comment: It was NOT me who asked the question. It was someone else. Yeah the title is really stupid. Still I felt closing was not justified.

Comment: @Silicomancer It wasn't; but I understand why it *was* closed. I had to read the question *very* carefully to find the problem statement.

Comment: @Silicomancer I edited to mention the OP instead of you. Sorry for the confusion.